# NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError[AviorBackendService]: NullInjectorError: No provider for even though the service is provided

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I have my test code here:

```
import { TestBed, inject } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { AviorBackendService } from './avior-backend.service';
import { HttpClientTestingModule, HttpTestingController } from '@angular/common/http/testing';

describe('AviorBackendService', () => {
  beforeEach(() => TestBed.configureTestingModule({imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
    providers: [ AviorBackendService ]}));

  it('should be created', () => {
    const service: AviorBackendService = TestBed.get(AviorBackendService);
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  });
});

it('expects service to fetch data with proper sorting', () => {
      const service: AviorBackendService = TestBed.get(AviorBackendService);
      // tslint:disable-next-line: prefer-const
      let httpMock: HttpTestingController;
      service.getUserCollection().subscribe(data => {
      expect(data.length).toBe(7);
      const req = httpMock.expectOne('http://localhost:3000/users');
      expect(req.request.method).toEqual('GET');      // Then we set the fake data to be returned by the mock
      req.flush({firstname: 'Chad'});
      });
    });

it('should create the Preferences Service', inject([AviorBackendService], (service: AviorBackendService) => {
          expect(service).toBeTruthy();
        }));
```

As you can see the AviorBackendService is provided, but still the error gets thrown out for the second and third tests. How to solve this? I tried changing it to declarations but that gave me other new errors so it seems to be not a proper solution.

Comment: Please provide the file without the problematic parts "commented out". On the first look it seems like you are providing the service just in the first "describe"-block, but the problematic "it"-blocks are *outside* of the describe block.

Comment: @PhilippMeissner I removed the non-functional code. So you're saying only my indentation is wrong?

Comment: Yes, move the `it`-blocks inside the wrapping `describe` block, which also includes the `beforeEach` block and you are good to go :)

Comment: Ah of course tslink caused this problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only providing the service for a single test, namely the first one.
The `beforeEach` block is scoped inside the `describe` block. That means all `it` blocks inside the `describe` block will have access to the provided service, but none outside.

Here's the updated version that should work.

```
import {HttpClientTestingModule, HttpTestingController} from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import {inject, TestBed} from '@angular/core/testing';
import {AviorBackendService} from './avior-backend.service';

describe('AviorBackendService', () => {
  beforeEach(() => TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
    providers: [AviorBackendService],
  }));

  it('should be created', () => {
    const service: AviorBackendService = TestBed.get(AviorBackendService);
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('expects service to fetch data with proper sorting', () => {
    const service: AviorBackendService = TestBed.get(AviorBackendService);
    // tslint:disable-next-line: prefer-const
    let httpMock: HttpTestingController;
    service.getUserCollection().subscribe(data => {
      expect(data.length).toBe(7);
      const req = httpMock.expectOne('http://localhost:3000/users');
      expect(req.request.method).toEqual('GET');      // Then we set the fake data to be returned by the mock
      req.flush({firstname: 'Chad'});
    });
  });

  it('should create the Preferences Service', inject([AviorBackendService], (service: AviorBackendService) => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  }));
});
```

The method provided to the `beforeEach` block will run before each `it` block and initialize your TestBed with the service you were missing before.

Comment: Maybe you have any clue why also the test passes even though I change the condition to an invalid one?

Comment: You most likely want to use the `done` method to tell your test suite that this is an asynchronous task.
Here's a gist: https://gist.github.com/PhilippMeissner/a96c2686cad6214dc3261b3b48162c98

Comment: It throws the error `Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.`

Comment: Hm, I would have to see the entire implementation for that case. Just double-checked your code here, it's not enough to find a concrete answer I fear. Best bet is to create a Stackblitz with the given code.

Comment: Ah sorry I misclicked and edited not my question but your answer. You have the code now nonetheless. Reject the code and copy it over to yourself.

Comment: I posted an extra question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60042200/how-to-write-a-unit-test-for-an-async-method