# How to write a unit test for an async method?

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have the following test code:

```js
import {HttpClientTestingModule, HttpTestingController} from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import {inject, TestBed} from '@angular/core/testing';
import {AviorBackendService} from './avior-backend.service';

describe('AviorBackendService', () => {
  beforeEach(() => TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
    providers: [AviorBackendService],
  }));

  it('should be created', () => {
    const service: AviorBackendService = TestBed.get(AviorBackendService);
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  });

  // Inject the `done` method. This will tell the test suite that asynchronous methods are being called
  // and it will mark the test as failed if within a specific timeout (usually 5s) the `done` is not called
  it('expects service to fetch data with proper sorting', (done) => {
    const service: AviorBackendService = TestBed.get(AviorBackendService);
    // tslint:disable-next-line: prefer-const
    let httpMock: HttpTestingController;
    service.getUserCollection().subscribe(data => {
      expect(data.length).toBe(7);
      const req = httpMock.expectOne('http://localhost:3000/users');
      expect(req.request.method).toEqual('GET');      // Then we set the fake data to be returned by the mock
      req.flush({firstname: 'Chad'});
      done(); // Mark the test as done
    }, done.fail); // Mark the test as failed if something goes wrong
  });
});
```

I need to write a prototype test for the supplied function (then I'll write the rest for the other similar functions). I am still learning how to write tests and as far I as I understand I need to use a mock, but I don't understand how.
My code to test is:

```js
  getUserCollection() {
    // withCredentials is very important as it passes the JWT cookie needed to authenticate
    return this.client.get<User[]>(SERVICE_URL + 'users', { withCredentials: true });
  }
```

My test code gives out an error `Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.`

**UPDATE**

My user-collection.model.ts:

```
import { User } from './user.model';

export interface UserCollection {

    user: User[];

}
```

My user.model.ts:

```
import { Role } from './role';

// was class and not interface!
export interface User {
    _id: number;
    mandator?: number;
    loginId: string;
    lastname: string;
    firstname: string;
    password: string;
    eMail: string;
    group?: string;
    role?: Role;
    active?: boolean;
    token?: string;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing the `flush` in a wrong location (a place that will never be traversed).

Try the following:

```
describe('AviorBackendService', () => {
  let httpTestingController: HttpTestingController;
  let service: AviorBackendService;

  beforeEach(() => {
   TestBed.configureTestingModule({
     imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
     providers: [AviorBackendService],
   });

   httpTestingController = TestBed.get(HttpTestingController);
   service = TestBed.get(AviorBackendService);
  });

  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('expects the service to fetch data with proper sorting', () => {
    const mockReponse = { firstName: 'Chad' };

    service.getUserCollection().subscribe(data => {
      expect(data.firstName).toEqual('Chad');
    });
    const req = httpTestingController.expectOne('IN HERE PUT WHATEVER SERVICE_URL + 'users' EQUALS TO');
    expect(req.request.method).toEqual('POST');
    // send the response to the subscribe.
    req.flush(mockResponse);
  });
});
```

A good link on how to test HTTP Service in Angular (https://medium.com/better-programming/testing-http-requests-in-angular-with-httpclienttestingmodule-3880ceac74cf)

Comment: I get `Error: Expected one matching request for criteria "Match URL: localhost:3000/users", found none.` and also in the `service.getUserCollection().subscribe(data => {
      expect(data.firstname).toEqual('Namehere');
    });` part it throws `Property 'firstname' does not exist on type 'User[]'.`...

Comment: Yes, because it is not `localhost:3000/users`. What is `SERVICE_URL`? Instead of putting `localhost:3000/users`, put `SERVICE_URL/users` but you have to figure out what the actual value of `SERVICE_URL` is and use that. The other issue is that in your service you have `<User[]>`, so does it return an array of users? If so, do `const mockResponse = [{ firstName: 'Chad' }];`.

Comment: SERVICE_URL is localhost:3000. Yes, that's the case.

Comment: Try doing `const mockResponse = [{ firstName: 'Chad' } as User];`. In terms of `SERVICE_URL` being `localhost`, see if it is `https://localhost:3000` instead. And also, in the beginning of the `it` test, `console.log(service.SERVICE_URL)`. If `SERVICE_URL` is not public, make it public for just this `console.log` to see its actual value.

Comment: By putting `as User` I get `Conversion of type '{ firstName: string; }' to type 'User' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first.
  Type '{ firstName: string; }' is missing the following properties from type 'User': _id, loginId, lastname, firstname, and 2 more.` No, it's http:// and not https://. If I put `console.log` I get `Property 'SERVICE_URL' does not exist on type 'AviorBackendService'.` and get `Property 'firstName' does not exist on type 'User[]'.`How do I make SERVICE_URL public?

Comment: I tried adding `public` before `const SERVICE_URL = 'http://localhost:3000/';` but that doesn't work

Comment: Maybe I should export it instead? I tried it out but the error does not vanish...

Comment: Then try doing `req.flush(mockResponse as any)` for the types issue. What is `SERVICE_URL`, a const or an instance variable? Try putting right above the constructor as `readonly SERVICE_URL = 'http://localhost:3000/';`, and in your service refer to it as `this.SERVICE_URL` (it's an instance variable now).

Comment: SERVICE_URL is a (global/public?) const but I can change it if needed.

Comment: Adding `as any` to the `flush` does not solve any of the errors. The const is put at the very top right after imports.

Comment: Moving the const and changing it to readonly solved one of the problems, but the conversion of type and property 'firstName' does not exist remain..

Comment: Adding the other ids, names etc seems to have solved the problem now only getting it to work is the problem. I commented out the following error but it does not seem to work. And also getting rid of `Property 'firstName' does not exist on type 'User[]'.`

Comment: Is there a colleague you can ask for help from? Right here, it is tough because I don't see the full picture. I am guessing with try this or that.

Comment: Apparently SO is the only help I can get right now :/